# Django RawQuerySet not working as expected

Tags: django

I ran a raw query just as the Django docs point:

```
Model.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM model')
```

and I got this result, Why it only shows the object?

```
<RawQuerySet: 'SELECT * FROM model'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because one (very powerful) feature of a queryset is, that it does not hit the database until necessary. You might slice it to get the results.

```
Model.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM model')[:]
```

Read the first paragraph of [the queryset docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) to learn more about other ways to execute the underlying query.