# display rawqueryset value in a model using django @property field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to insert a @property field into a django model.
However this field gets its value from a RawQuerySet like so;

```
class Medication_List(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    medication_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, editable=True)
...

    def stock_level(self):
       # "Returns the totalstock remaining"
        current_stock = Medications_Bridge.objects.raw("SELECT  T3.total_quantity_sold AS total_quantity_sold FROM (SELECT  * FROM ...

        return({'current_stock' : current_stock}) 

    stock = property(stock_level)

    def __str__(self):          
    return "%s %s %s" % (self.medication_name, self.supplier,self.stock)
```

This works fine with no errors, but django is not showing value for the queryset in the **str** function, rather it just shows the whole query just as  it was written above. i.e.  "SELECT  T3.total_quantity....."

I want to know if it is even possible to use @property field to show a value from another unrelated database table.

I have seen some examples on StackOverflow where calculated  values are shown using values from the same model with help of self.field_name but i cant find any example where the values for  the calculations are derived from another model or from a raw SQL query.

Kindly help. Any hint will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay so upon further reading, i just found from this post

[Django RawQuerySet not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255458/django-rawqueryset-not-working-as-expected)

that QuerySets in django are not evaluated until necessary, that is, it does not hit the database until necessary.

Upon following the links to the QuerySet API i was able to find a way to do exactly what i wanted.

As is mostly always the case, you find the answer soon after you blurt out the question. LOL